# Why does cleveref change theorem style unexpectedly?

Tags: cleveref

I observe the style of a theorem that uses a shared counter being changed unexpectedly when `cleveref` is used.

I expect all new theorems to have the default style `plain` as in `asmbook`, with small caption title font and italic body font.

However, when `cleveref` is used, the `fact` theorem, which shares a counter with the `lemma` theorem, changes its style unexpectedly.

I attempt to fix it by explicitly stating `\theoremstyle{plain}` before creating `fact`. However, it does not work.
Then, I create a new theorem style `factstyle` and hardcode the `plain` style in it. This can fix the issue.

I notice that if the document class is just `document`, there is no such issue. I also acknowledge that `hyperref` needs to be declared before `cleveref` and all `\newtheorem` definitions must be placed after the `cleveref` package is loaded.

What is going on here? Does `cleveref` have conflict with `asmbook` style?

Here are the code to reproduce the issue and the fixes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,reqno]{amsbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\DeclareOption*

\ProcessOptions

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

% Plain style
\newtheorem{remark}{remark}

%%%%%%
% Style Fix
% \newtheoremstyle{factstyle}% name of the style to be used
%   {}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
%   {}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
%   {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
%   {1.5em}% measure of space to indent
%   {\scshape}% name of head font
%   {.}% punctuation between head and body
%   { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
%   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\textnormal{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}
% \theoremstyle{factstyle}
%%%%%%

% Should be Plain style but changed by cleveref?
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{fact}[lemma]{Fact}

\begin{document}

\section{Cleveref changes theorem style unexpectedly}

\begin{lemma}
    This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{remark}
    This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{fact}
    This is a fact.
    This should look like remark however it looks differently.
    
    When Fact shares the counter with Lemma, its style changes if cleveref is used.

    To fix: Uncomment "Style Fix", or stop using cleveref.
\end{fact}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsbook` doesn't load `amsthm`, because it uses built-in styles based on it. Apparently this confuses `cleveref`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `amsthm` should be loaded before `cleveref`. However, `amsbook` disables loading `amsthm`, because it has it built-in.

The way `amsbook` disables loading `amsthm` has the consequence that `amsthm` passes the `\@ifpackageloaded` test, which `cleveref` relies on. Chaos ensues.

Likely, `cleveref` should also have a test for the class being `amsart` or `amsbook`, so this conflict (possibly) doesn't happen. Below is a workaround.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,reqno]{amsbook}

%%% undo amsbook settings similar to amsthm
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsthm.sty\endcsname\relax
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\pushQED\relax
\let\popQED\relax
\let\qedhere\relax
\let\mathqed\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
%%% now loading amsthm is possible
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%% emulate the plain theorem style of amsbook
\newtheoremstyle{amsbookplain}% name of the style to be used
  {}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {\parindent}% measure of space to indent
  {\scshape}% name of head font
  {.}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\textnormal{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{amsbookplain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{fact}[lemma]{Fact}
\newtheorem{remark}{remark}

%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{Cleveref changes theorem style unexpectedly}

\begin{lemma}
    This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{remark}
    This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{fact}
    This is a fact.
    This should look like remark however it looks differently.
    
    When Fact shares the counter with Lemma, its style changes if cleveref is used.

    To fix: Uncomment "Style Fix", or stop using cleveref.
\end{fact}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I found a note earlier at
http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/anthony.roberts/LaTeX/ltxstyle.php
that also mentions unloading things, but I wasn't able to comprehend it until now.

Comment: If I try this workaround with the document class `amsart` (which is not necessary, since everything seems to work anyway), then the spaces between two environments are smaller. This confuses me, since the `\theoremstyle{default}` should be the same.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek The hack isn't necessary with `amsart`, as you discovered. Why are the spaces different? The empty first two arguments are the answer: add the desired amount of space there.